# Can anyone point me to good guides on using django.contrib.sites for multiple views on the same database?

Tags: python, django

[Warning - python noob]

I have read what I can find and got sites up and running with one "site" in the database. I'm not sure where to go from here. What is the right folder structure for the code for the second site? It's going to re-use models (I assume - DRY) so presumably needs to use the same app folders - but the documentation talks about it using different settings files. This is where I got a bit lost.

Secondarily, I'd love pointers to how to run the development server and how to run apache for multiple sites.

Thanks in advance.

Update: I am particularly interested where settings vary between sites - e.g. one uses authentication to place everything behind a login and the other doesn't. As per a conversation below, does that mean two separate projects? They are using the same models, so how do I follow DRY?

My actual situation is as follows:

example1.com is an in-house project management tool - it uses google apps authentication so you can't see any pages unless you are authenticated against the company google account.

I want to create example2.com which is a view over certain kinds of open tasks (created via example1.com) so that freelancers can see available jobs and claim them. They don't have google apps accounts and so example2.com is going to use different authentication.

Both share models (e.g. "projects", "jobs") and both need to read from the same database. What's the best way of achieving this in django? Sorry if this wasn't clear - I was trying to keep the question abstract but this is why I referred to different settings files in my original question.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are you managing the google apps authentication?

Comment: I'm using this: https://github.com/hudora/django-googleappsauth - it took me some fiddling to get it working, but I suspect that was because it was my first ever django project and I didn't really know what I was doing. Once I got everything in the right place, it "just worked".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my preferred setup.

example1.com (with GA authentication) should be served by Apache (via mod_wsgi) and references some suite of Django Apps that use your only database.

example2.com should also be served by the the same Apache (via mod_wsgi) and references some suite of Django Apps that use your only database.

The example1.com is a "Location" in Apache that references an "/var/www/example1/example1.wsgi" file.  This file is associated with a specific `example1/settings.py` for example1.com's suite of applications and configuration.

The example2.com is a "Location" in Apache that references an "/var/www/example1/example2.wsgi" file.  This file is associated with a specific `example2/settings.py` for example2.com's suite of applications and configuration.

Some Django applications might be shared between the two locations.  Some applications might be specific to one location or the other.

The database is totally shared between the two locations.

---

Using Sites

The second site is built with the same code as the first site.  It's not a copy or a clone.  You have one group of applications that use one database.

The "site" is something users see.  The "site" is a consequence of how you fetch data and use templates to present things to users.  But it's all one project of applications.

The user-perceived "sites" only differ by one thing: the `site` key that you put into your models.

Often, you'll do things like use Apache to redirect different domain names to URL's with "site" keys.

If you're building multiple sites that do not share the same code, then you're just building a lot of applications, perhaps in different projects.

Specific use cases are here:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/sites/#how-django-uses-the-sites-framework

> It’s a hook for associating objects
>   and functionality to particular Web
>   sites, and it’s a holding place for
>   the domain names and “verbose” names
>   of your Django-powered sites.

Comment: So where different sites need different settings I should just use if statements within the main settings.py?

Comment: @willcritchlow: That's not part of your question.  Please **update** your question.  The answer is No.  If you need settings which vary between sites, you should not use the Sites framework.  If you need settings which vary between sites, you simply have multiple Django applications, each with their own settings.

Comment: I have updated the question - this was what I was getting at with the original comment about different settings files. I have now added more detail about what I'm actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to accomplish is not provided by django, but can be done by configuring your server. Here are examples of doing this with [mod_wsgi](http://forum.webfaction.com/viewtopic.php?id=2400) or with [mod_python](http://forum.webfaction.com/viewtopic.php?id=42)

Though, this is somewhat advanced. I would recommend deploying a couple of simple django applications, and then trying this out.